# c++ noob coder questions

Tags: c++, loops

```
using namespace std;
int main() 
{
  cout << "\n\n Find the perfect numbers between 1 and 500:\n";
  cout << "------------------------------------------------\n";
  int i = 1, u = 1, sum = 0;
  cout << "\n The perfect numbers between 1 to 500 are: \n";
  while (i <= 500) 
  {
    while (u <= 500) 
    {
      if (u < i) 
      {
        if (i % u == 0)
          sum = sum + u;
      }
      u++;
    }
    if (sum == i) {
      cout << i << "  " << "\n";
    }
    i++;
    u = 1;
    sum = 0;
  }
}
```

why we added **u=1** and **sum=o** in the last two lines? Can somebody help me with this? I am not able to comprehend the logic behind changing the logic at the end.

Comment: Remove the lines one at a time and see what happens. Then spend some time thinking about how it happens.

Comment: What's that code supposed to do? Should we guess?

Comment: Would it make more sense to you if you moved those two lines to right before `while (u <= 500)`? You could also just move `int u = 1, sum = 0;` from outside the loop into the outer loop right before the inner loop starts and remove the two lines you've asked about..

Comment: the "last two lines" are inside a loop.

Comment: Is your instructor showing you the equivalence of `for` and `while`?

Comment: @Caleth no actually i am trying to learn from GFG and other websites. Can you suggest me a way i can improve my logic in loop controls. I am having a hard time doing it.

Comment: This example would normally be written `for (int i = 1; i <= 500; i++) for (int u = 1; u < i; u++)` , and not distribute the loop variable all across the program

Answer (score 1):

Those lines are for re-initializing the variables.
The code you have posted is for finding the perfect numbers which are just numbers that equals the sum of its own proper divisors. eg: 6, the proper divisors are 1, 2, 3. sum of 1 + 2 + 3 = 6. So, 6 is a perfect number.

The first while loop

```
while (i <= 500)
```

is for going through the numbers between 1 and 500 one by one
and the second while loop

```
while (u <= 500)
```

is for checking the divisors for a particular i. At first the loop will run for i = 1, the second while loop runs for 500 times and check the divisors of 1. Now, for i = 2, we have to check the divisors again from u = 1 right, so the re-initialization is done after the second while loop.

actually you should change the second loop to

```
while (u < i)
```

or even better

```
while (u <= (i / 2))
```